# Is it possible to detect subjective decoherence? If yes, how?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

In his [paper from 1994](https://homepages.fhv.at/tb/cms/?download=tbDISS.pdf) Thomas Breuer describes a phenomenon of subjective decoherence (p. 43). I wonder whether it can be measured, and if yes, how.

I also wonder whether it would allow to create an all-win lottery that can make everybody happy.

Suppose a lottery is conducted. The winner is awarded a billion dollars plus the title of eternal Earth dictator.

The winner is determined in the following way.

- There is a thoroughly isolated black box inside which a pretender is
  placed.
- Inside the box an apparatus measures subjective decoherence.
- If subjective decoherence is found, the pretender declared the
  winner.

It follows that any person, when he or she is observing the lottery from outside will see all other pretenders to loose.

At the same time any participant that tries the lottery himself will find himself a winner.

This is a fascinating lottery which will make all the participation pretenders the winners in their own eyes. Each person who goes through this machine will see other people to congratulate them, to proclaim them the eternal emperor and so on.